# Firefox cuts text off in ::after element

Tags: html, css, firefox

i have got several `::after` elements with text. Firefox is cutting off some letters - but not in a line (see picture). I wanted to find the mistake, but when I open the developer tools the text is rendered correctly. I do not understand this. in safari and chrome everything is fine...

Missing:
[image: missing]

Not missing:
[image: not missing]

Here is the after-Elements CSS-Code:

```
font-size: 15px;
hyphens: none;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1.3em;
```

Comment: We need to see a [mre] of the code to be able to help beyond just making some guesses/assumptions. Can you add the HTML and relevant CSS used to create the images you shared?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce it on jsfiddle, but it is not easy to reproduce this never seen before effect...

Comment: The easiest way is to copy all your code over to JSFiddle and then start deleting stuff you know or think isn't related to reproducing that issue. Once you have removed all the superfluous HTML and CSS, any additional lines of code you remove should have a visible effect. That's your minimal example, and you can copy that HTML and CSS over here to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the mistake. It was a mistake in the font-family, not an issue in firefox. curious thing for me: after opening developer tools it seems to render or load again and so the text was rigth displayed.